# How to print a table with nested loops in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to print an array of objects in a nested loop, let's say you have:

```
data=[{a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'},{a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'},{a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'}];
```

now I want to display this array in a table:

```
{ data.map(
    (row,index)=>
   {
    return(
      <tr key={index}>
        {Object.keys(row).map(column=>{
          return (
            <td>{row[column]}</td>
          );
        })}
      </tr>
    );
   }
  )}
```

Unfortunately I get this error `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` , it seems as if I do not have access to the row inside the map. I want to print the content of the row for each of the columns.

Comment: You're trying to display an object, you can't do that. `{row[column]}` returns `{a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}` and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't render an object. You can loop through the data again and render each value in the objects if that's your goal.

```
Object.keys(data).map(col => {
  Object.keys(data[col]).map(row => <td>{row}</td>)
})
```